# Tkinter button tooltip threading issue

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

Hi I'm trying to a create Tkinter buttons that have a tooltip bubble on hover. I want the tooltip to be time delayed on enter and only display for a certain amount of time. I'm using threading to display the tooltip as to not block the button from being clicked. I seem to be very close to a solution but there is a problem that I think that is related to the threads. The tooltip is a toplevel window without any window decorations(title bar, borders, etc). When entering the button the tooltip is displayed but sometimes it has decorations and sometimes it don't, also sometimes it appears in the correct position and sometimes it don't. I have no idea why this behaviour is happening, below I posted the test code I'm using to solve this problem, but now I'm lost any help would would be appreciated.

```
from time import sleep
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label, Toplevel
from threading import Thread


class _Button(Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self.tooltip_text = kwargs.pop('tooltip', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.t = None
        self.parent = parent
        self.btn_tooltip = None

    def tooltip(self):
        if not self.t:
            self.t = Thread(target=self.tooltip_render)
            self.t.start()

    def tooltip_render(self):
        sleep(0.5)
        if not self.btn_tooltip:
            self.btn_tooltip = Toplevel()
            self.btn_tooltip.wm_overrideredirect(True)

            x, y, cx, cy = self.bbox('insert')
            x += self.winfo_rootx() + 25
            y += self.winfo_rooty() + 25

            self.btn_tooltip.geometry('+%d+%d' % (x, y))
            label = Label(
                self.btn_tooltip, text=self.tooltip_text, background='yellow', borderwidth=1,
            )
            label.pack(ipadx=5, ipady=2)

            sleep(1)
            if self.btn_tooltip:
                self.btn_tooltip.destroy()
                self.btn_tooltip = None
                self.t = None


def enter(e):
    e.widget.tooltip()


def leave(e):
    if e.widget.btn_tooltip:
        e.widget.btn_tooltip.destroy()
        e.widget.btn_tooltip = None
        e.widget.t = None


root = Tk()

bt1 = _Button(root, text='Button 1', tooltip='Tooltip1')
bt1.bind('<Enter>', enter)
bt1.bind('<Leave>', leave)
bt1.grid()

bt2 = _Button(root, text='Button 2', tooltip='Tooltip2')
bt2.bind('<Enter>', enter)
bt2.bind('<Leave>', leave)
bt2.grid(row=0, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need threads to do this, and in fact threads make the problem much more difficult. Are you interested in a solution that doesn't use threads?

Comment: Yes I just don't want the tooltip to block input, it just needs to popup after a delay then disappear after a second or so. I have tried after() but it to blocks input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel, TclError, Label, Button


class Tooltip:
    def __init__(self, widget, text, delay=750, duration=1500):
        self.widget = widget
        self._tooltip = None

        self._hide_id = None
        self._render_id = None
        self._tooltip_text = text
        self._tooltip_delay = delay
        self._tooltip_duration = duration

        self._enter_bind = self.widget.bind("<Enter>", self.show)
        self._leave_bind = self.widget.bind("<Leave>", self.hide)
        self._button_bind = self.widget.bind("<Button>", self.hide)

    def __del__(self):
        try:
            self.widget.unbind("<Enter>", self._enter_bind)
            self.widget.unbind("<Leave>", self._leave_bind)
            self.widget.unbind("<Button>", self._button_bind)
        except TclError:
            pass

    def show(self, _):
        def render():
            if not self._tooltip:
                self._tooltip = tw = Toplevel(self.widget)
                tw.wm_overrideredirect(True)

                x, y = 20, self.widget.winfo_height() + 1
                root_x = self.widget.winfo_rootx() + x
                root_y = self.widget.winfo_rooty() + y
                self._tooltip.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (root_x, root_y))

                label = Label(
                    self._tooltip,
                    text=self._tooltip_text,
                    justify='left',
                    background="#ffffe0",
                    relief='solid',
                    borderwidth=1
                )
                label.pack()
                self._tooltip.update_idletasks()  # Needed on MacOS -- see #34275.
                self._tooltip.lift()
                self._hide_id = self.widget.after(self._tooltip_duration, self.hide)

        if self._tooltip_delay:
            if self._render_id:
                self.widget.after_cancel(self._render_id)
            self._render_id = self.widget.after(self._tooltip_delay, render)
        else:
            render()

    def hide(self, _=None):
        try:
            if self._hide_id:
                self.widget.after_cancel(self._hide_id)
            if self._render_id:
                self.widget.after_cancel(self._render_id)
        except TclError:
            pass

        tooltip = self._tooltip
        if self._tooltip:
            try:
                tooltip.destroy()
            except TclError:
                pass
            self._tooltip = None


def app():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Test tooltip")

    button1 = Button(top, text="Button 1")
    button1.pack()
    Tooltip(button1, "Tooltip for Button 1", delay=500, duration=1500)

    button2 = Button(top, text="Button 2")
    button2.pack()
    Tooltip(button2, "Tooltip for Button 2", delay=0, duration=1500)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tk = Tk()

    app(tk)

    tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just a bunch of working code without an explanation doesn't make for a good answer. You might want to consider summarizing what you did.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need threading to have a tooltip appear and then disappear a few seconds later. Threading is difficult even when you have lots of experience with threading. It's even more difficult when you don't, and yet even more when combining it with an event-based program.

Instead, you should use the facilities that tkinter provides. Namely, the `after` method which can schedule code to run into the future.

All you need to do is use `after` to display your tooltip, and then use `after` again to dismiss it.

The basic pattern looks like this:

```
def tooltip_render(self):
    # create the tooltip
    self.btn_tooltip = Toplevel()
    ... 
    <the rest of your code to render the tooltip> 
    ...

    # schedule it to go away
    self.after(1000, self.btn_tooltip.destroy)
```

Next, call `render_tooltip` again using `after`:

```
def tooltip(self):
    self.after(500, self.tooltip_render)
```

This alone will not give you perfect tooltips. You'll still need to protect against trying to render and destroy multiple tooltips if the user moves the mouse fast, but this gives you the general framework without having to resort to threading.

Comment: I did as you suggested and I now have a working model. Thank you.